# Grabbing the latest row by date, but grouped by a column in another table

Tags: mysql

edit: Here's a SQL Fiddle of the database: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf137/1

I've had a pretty lengthy search for this problem, and I've found similar questions that have helped me on my way, but can't quite get there on my own steam. Apologies if this is a duplicate!

What I want to do with this is get a list of body parts and the last day you worked them out. So JOIN both tables based on workouts.exercise and exercises.name, sort by workouts.date, then group by exercises.area.

**I just want to group by Area, and return the most recent (by Date field) row for each. So the most recent Chest, Shoulders, Legs, Back exercises performed.**

I've got the basics down here, but the date sorting refuses to work:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM workouts
    WHERE user = 1
    ORDER BY date DESC
) as workouts
JOIN (
    SELECT name, area
    FROM exercises
) exercises
ON workouts.exercise = exercises.name
GROUP BY area
```

If you run the SQLFiddle, you'll see that of the four Back exercises, the latest is not returned in the group. Ideally I should get this result (with cols removed for readability):

```
id  date                  exercise      name            area
5   2015-03-18 13:30:00   Bench press   Bench press     Chest
1   2015-03-04 15:04:00   Front raises  Front raises    Shoulders
3   2015-03-16 21:08:00   Squats        Squats          Legs
8   2015-03-23 12:03:00   Lat pulldowns Lat pulldowns   Back
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Of course. Apologies. I'll edit the question when I get home from work, unless someone has kindly solved it and beaten me to it by then!

Comment: I'm confused. You question sounds like you want to order by date, your fiddle orders properly, but your desired output is not sorted? Can you clearly state what you want?

Comment: Sorry, I'm being horrendously bad at explaining this, aren't I.

I just want to group by Area, and return the most recent (by Date field) row for each. So the most recent Chest, Shoulders, Legs, Back exercises performed.

Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT w.*
     , e.*
  FROM workouts w
  JOIN exercises e
    ON e.name = w.exercise
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT e.area
            , MAX(w.date) max_date 
         FROM exercises e 
         JOIN workouts w 
           ON w.exercise = e.name
        GROUP 
           BY e.area
     ) y
    ON y.area = e.area
   AND y.max_date = w.date;
```

(This might not be completely right)

Comment: That works perfectly. You're amazing. Apologies for making this so confusing!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MAX` function on `date` column:

```
SELECT MAX(w.date) date
, w.routine, w.exercise, e.area
FROM workouts w
INNER JOIN exercises e ON w.exercise = e.name
GROUP BY e.area;
```

Comment: Weirdly, that actually merges some data. The output for Back is Cable Rows on the 23rd March, but if you look at the dataset, the workout on that date is actually Lat Pulldowns! It might work, seeing as I'm only really interested in the bodypart exercised, not the exercise itself in this instance, but it's definitely not perfect!

Comment: You are right! indeed I missed this detail, the answer accepted deals with this